# my if and elif is not working properly how to fix? its only printing the first statement no matter what choice you pick

Tags: if-statement

```
peso_value = int(input("Enter PESO value:\n"))
print("""
Menu:
[A]Dollar
[B]Yen
[C]Rial
""")
choice = input("choice: ")
if choice == 'A' or 'a':
    print('\nDollar Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / 52.04))
elif choice == "B" or "b":
    print('\nYen Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / .048))
elif choice == "C" or "c":
    print('\nRiyal Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / 0.072))
else:
    print("Invalid Choice")
```

It only prints the dollar value no matter what choice you pick

Comment: what `if choice == 'A' or 'a':` does is to check if choice is equal A and if a is True (different from 0) and since it is different from 0, it passed every times. you have to put the variable twice to make it test both letter like that `if choice == 'A' or choice == 'a':`

Comment: thankyou i forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `choice == 'A' or 'a'`, it always evaluates to true as `'a'` evaluates to true, you have to do `choice == 'A' or choice == a`, 
or
You can make use of `upper()` function,

```
peso_value = int(input("Enter PESO value:\n"))
print("""
Menu:
[A]Dollar
[B]Yen
[C]Rial
""")
choice = input("choice: ")
if choice.upper() == 'A':
 print('\nDollar Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / 52.04))
elif choice.upper() == "B":
 print('\nYen Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / .048))
elif choice.upper() == "C":
 print('\nRiyal Value:%.2f' % (peso_value / 0.072))
else:
 print("Invalid Choice")
```